# Command line open pkg

Tags: macos, terminal, install, command-line

I am trying to write an app that will trigger an pkg to open so the user can install this. I have the code and it is working well except for the following.

When I try to open the pkg file using `open /tmp/mypackage.pkg` in most cases it will open the Finder to the users home folder not the package.

I have checked and the package is present within the specified directory and the application is creating the correct command.

The command i am using to do this is in python:

```
subprocess.Popen(['open', '/tmp/mypackage.pkg'])
application.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

From the command line you could use

```
sudo installer -pkg /tmp/mypackage.pkg -target /
```

I assume you can incorporate this into your python application.

Comment: I want to be able to use open only becuase I want to show the installer UI to the user.